# Galaxy S7 can't reboot. E:failed to mount /system (Invalid argument)

Tags: 7.0-nougat, unbricking, samsung-galaxy-s7

I got a brand new Verizon(unlocked) Galaxy S7 with Marshmallow on it. Tried to upgrade to Nougat using Smart Switch which got stuck at 36% for hours. Had to unplug and plug back back for recovery but in vain (my device didn't show up in Emergency Recovery).
I went into recovery mode and wiped cache and Factory reset but no use. My device refused to boot.

At the top of recovery screen, I see this

```
Verizon/heroqltevzw/heroqltevzw
7.0/NRD90M/G930VVRU4BQH4
```

And, at the bottom, below Error:

```
No Support SINGLE-SKU
dm-verify API: 3
E:failed to mount /system (Invalid argument)
```

Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: The system partition is damaged/corrupted. You should now try flashing with Odin. Download ROM manually from the internet then flash your phone is Download mode.

Comment: Glad I helped. I could make it an answer which you can accept, so this will help people on same situation than you were.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the system partition is damaged/corrupted.

You should now flash the phone with [Odin](https://odindownload.com/) if using Windows computer or [Heindal](http://glassechidna.com.au/heimdall/) on a Mac.

Download the [firmware](https://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/galaxy-s7/SM-G930V/VZW/) manually from the internet then flash your phone in Download Mode (Volume down + power button).  Also download Samsung USB drivers (Windows).